# What is the correct way to check if an unknown Callable is a specific builtin function?

Tags: python

I have an unknown `x: Union[Callable[..., Any], str]` (question title doesn't mention `str` but please consider that as a possibility). How might I check something along the lines of `x == math.sqrt`?

For context, this is part of a functionality which is meant to symbolically trace Python code for the purpose of being able to then apply transformations to the logic.

Comment: Have you tried just `x == math.sqrt`? That looks like it would work.

Comment: In a python interpreter yes, but something funny is happening in this code which is causing that to return `False`. Working on reproducing it somehow.

Comment: Make sure you're importing the correct function in each case. There's likely multiple modules that have a `sqrt` function.

Comment: When you get to where the comparison is happening and is returning false, print out each function directly. It would be interesting to see what the output is.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `x` was `<built-in function sqrt>` and printing `math.sqrt` gives `<function sqrt at 0x7f91540fc820>` even after reimporting `math` (in `pdb` that is`. Get the feeling this is some Python black box stuff that I haven't figured out yet

Comment: How is `math.sqrt` being imported/created?

Comment: `import math`    .

Comment: Ah, I'll admit that I don't have much experience with `pdb`, so it could be due to the internals of it. In most cases, modules are cached when they're imported, so I'd expect all instances of imported functions to match. `<function sqrt at 0x7f91540fc820>` looks like a local function definition though, so if that's not something you're doing, it could be an optimization they're using. It's only in the debugger that it's happening?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I assume it's not only debugger as `==` doesn't hold. Thanks for checking it out anway!